# Asp.net Regular expression to support multiple languages

Tags: asp.net

I have asp.net RegularExpressionValidator
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z\?*.\?!\@#\%\&\~`\$\^_\,()\//]{1,30}$" />
It will support any alpha numeric charectors excepts script tags. right now it wont supports any other language except english.

I want modify this regular  expression to support arabic  charectors also.
Please help me how to modify this expression..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: It would help if you told us what you are trying to "validate".

Answer (score 1):

You essentially need to change your regex from a whitelist to a blacklist. So you want to check for characters that you *don't* want to allow. You can achieve this by starting your regex with a ^ inside the opening bracket. So

```
ValidationExpression="[^\?*.\?!\@#\%\&\~`\$\^_\,()\//]"
```

will pass any string that does not contain the characters in the expression.

Comment: I do not recommend using blacklists; they are fail-unsafe. If anything goes wrong or changes, or if your characters are ever mapped, translated, bit-stripped, or a thousand other things happen, blacklists allow invalid characters. Stick with whitelists, they are fail-safe. If a whitelist breaks it will forbid a valid character, which is annoying but not a security vulnerability.

Comment: I want to add limit the number of charector it will accept say for example it should accept only 200 charectors, since it is a asp.net TextBox(multiline)

Answer (score 0):

You can add Arabic characters to regular expressions; they match themselves. One problem with Unicode is that Arabic digits, punctuation, and ornaments are scattered around in code blocks, so you may have to add specific symbols you are looking for:

```
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z\?*.\?!\@#\%\&\~`\$\^_\,()\//\u0621-\u063F\u066E-\u06D3]{1,30}$"
```